# How to use setInterval and clearInterval in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

This is my JS in nodeJS :

```
function test(a, room, seconds) {
    console.log(a, room, seconds);
}

intervalid = setInterval(test, 1000, 'room', 20);
console.log('intervalid', intervalid);
```

Which returns the output:

```
intervalid Timeout {
    _called: false,
    _idleTimeout: 1000,
    _idlePrev: TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
        _unrefed: false,
        msecs: 1000,
        nextTick: false
    },
    _idleNext: TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
        _unrefed: false,
        msecs: 1000,
        nextTick: false
    },
    _idleStart: 377,
    _onTimeout: [Function: test],
    _timerArgs: [ 'room', 20 ],
    _repeat: 1000
}
```

Whereas in simple JavaScript, it returns a simple integer.

When I attach interval to an existing user object, example:

```
user.intervalid = setInterval(test, 1000, 'room', 20);
```

I am not able to clearInterval any more:

```
clearInterval(user.intervalid); // does not work
```

Comment: It should work just fine, provided that `user` is the same object that you used when you stored the return value of `setInterval`. In other words, `user` can't in the meantime have been converted to/from JSON, for instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Whereas in simple Javascript it returns a simple INTEGER number" ?

Comment: Js returns int and nodejs returns object

Comment: Ok, first of all, you need to be aware that your `setInterval` call is missing a parameter because the call is of the form : `setInterval(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);`. Second of all, if your problem is that you are not able to clear the interval, then you need to paste the code for the user object and whichever code is modifying your `intervalid` object.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a JavaScript like interval ID after creating a `setInterval` timer, you can do the following,

```
function callbackFunc() {
  console.log("I'm just an example callback function");
}

const timeoutObj = setInterval(callbackFunc, 1000);
const intervalId = timeoutObj[Symbol.toPrimitive](); //intervalId is an interger

// Later you can clear the timer by calling clearInterval with the intervalId like,
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Note: This only works when your node version is >= `v12.19.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me as I was using dynamic intervals in NestJS

Comment: so I'm using setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(intervalId); }, 20000); to set timeout, but what if I want to call another function after the interval is cleared?

Answer (score 6):

You can use **"this"** in the following example:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const message = Buffer.from('from raspberry pi 3');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var count = 0;

function intervalFunc() {
  count++;
  client.send(message, 3001, 'localhost', (err) => {
    //client.close();
  });
  if (count == '5') {
    clearInterval(this);
  }
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);
```

Comment: Kindly note that you cannot use arrow function in the above example, as "this" does not work in arrow function.

Answer (score 4):

This just caught me. Exactly the same scenario, clearInterval simply wasn't working.

Looking in the console, the result of setInterval was an object, not a number. I was quite confused.

The solution was to remove this import statement, which had snuck in:

`import { setInterval } from 'timers';`

Comment: You're a lifesaver! XD

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` takes a function argument that will run an infinite number of times with a given millisecond delay as the second argument.

```
setInterval(()=> {
  console.log('Every 1 second');
},1000)
console.log('I will run first');
```

**How to use `clearInterval()`:**

```
var xyz = setInterval(()=> {
  console.log('Every 1 second');
},1000)
console.log('I will run first');

clearInterval(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of these functions are:
Task: give a clap once every 5 seconds and stop doing this after 20 seconds.

`setInterval(clap_your_hands,5 seconds)`: we are basically telling what to do, that is, to clap once after every 5 seconds
`clearInterval(stop_clapping)`: we are basically telling to clear what we were doing, stop clapping task and do nothing.

All above answers have talked about these two packages but there in one big flaw. They did not tell when to stop. Below is the result we see if we execute above answers. Remember, executing these two codes one after another, it happens so quickly that we don't see any output at all. This is like saying to clap and stop at same time. End result, we hear no clapping at all.

[image]

`setTimeout(doSomething_JustOnce_AfterThisTime,20seconds)`: we are basically telling to do something just once after 20 seconds and the result of using this package in the above is:
[image]

Here, we told to wait for 20 seconds, That's the reason, we see output for 20 seconds. In this case, console shows `room 20 undefined` printed to the console. `Undefined` because the `test` function was expecting three inputs but two only were given and function declares third as `undefined`.