# How to use setInterval in EJS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a problem with using setInterval in my EJS file, which is part of my nodejs app (with Express). I have created function **getRandomSubarray**, which chooses randomly subset of images from array. I want to change this subset every three seconds. This is problematic piece of my code:

`<%setInterval(function(){%>
<%RandomSubrecipesImg=tools.getRandomSubarray(recipesImg,4)%>

    <div class="navbar-image-box col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-block"><img class="navbar-image" src="<%=RandomSubrecipesImg[0].replace('public',"")%>"></div>
    <div class="navbar-image-box col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-block"><img class="navbar-image" src="<%=RandomSubrecipesImg[1].replace('public',"")%>"></div>
    <div class="navbar-image-box col-sm-3"><img class="navbar-image" src="<%=RandomSubrecipesImg[2].replace('public',"")%>"></div>
    <div class="navbar-image-box col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-block"><img class="navbar-image" src="<%=RandomSubrecipesImg[3].replace('public',"")%>"></div>
<% },3000);%>`

In browser I haven't received any divs. In case of removing setInterval I have div elements in browser, so I think there is something wrong with **setInterval**. Do you have any idea what is wrong
?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js: how to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588994/node-js-how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Comment: EJS is a template language, it creates static HTML markup. You cannot do any dynamic stuff with it, and you cannot use `setInterval`. If you want the divs to change randomly every few seconds in the browser, you will need a clientside script that does that.

Answer (score 1):

EJS is used for render things server-side. But setInterval is a client-side function which doenst need to be rendered.

Prepare your data serverside and send everything in init request, then start `setInterval` client-side and fetch the "new" data from your API - Endpoint. Could be done via AJAX or WebSockets.

Or you could setup an WebSocket and push "new" data to all clients.