# how i can add interval between two message?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
message.channel.send('hi')
after 5 second
message.channel.send('hi again)
```

person:?hi

bot:hi

after 5 second

bot:hi again

How i can do 5 second intervals in code?

Comment: Please see the setInterval function, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588994/node-js-how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js: how to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588994/node-js-how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `setTimeout()`. Take the time to learn basic JS before working in DJS

```
message.channel.send(...)

setTimeout(function(){
   message.channel.send(...)
}, 5000)
```

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

For repetition you would use `setInterval()` in the same fashion. Just be careful as making the bot do X every Y seconds is considered API spam.

Comment: accualy i dont try to be a codder i just need a basic discord bot :)
thx for help